# Copy and paste with conditions

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, copy, paste

I am looking to copy and paste certain rows if conditions are met. If cell is blank, then skip to next row.

The code below is not skipping the blank cells, and is instead copying and pasting everything from Sheet1 to DataTable worksheet. Unsure why
If Status <> "" is not filtering out the blanks.

```
Sub copypaste()
Dim Cell As Range
Dim CellCol As Range
Dim PasteCell As Range
Dim PasteCellAmount As Range
Dim DataTable As Worksheet

Set DataTable = Worksheets("Data")
Set CellCol = Sheet1.Range("C2:C50")

For Each Cell In CellCol
    'paste cells into blank row
    If DataTable.Range("A2") = "" Then
       Set PasteCell = DataTable.Range("A2")
       Set PasteCellAmount = DataTable.Range("C2")
    Else
       Set PasteCell = DataTable.Range("A2").Offset(1, 0)
       Set PasteCellAmount = DataTable.Range("C2").Offset(1, 0)
    End If
    
    'copy cell in Column A and C in the row with value
    If Cell <> "" Then 
    CellCol.Offset(0, -2).Copy PasteCell
    CellCol.Offset(0, 0).Copy PasteCellAmount
    
    Next cell

End sub
```

Comment: what is the goal of this?, because you are always copying into A2 and C2? right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(1)**  Your code is missing an `End If` statement (to close the last `If`), so it won't compile.

**(2)**  As you write `CellCol.Offset(0, -2)`, you will always copy the whole `CellCol`-Range ("C2:C50"). With other words: If at least one cell is not empty, the whole range is copied. If 30 cells are not empty, the range will copied 30 times, but that makes no difference.
What you (probably, I don't know your exact logic) need to do is use `cell`:

```
cell.Offset(0, -2).Copy PasteCell
cell.Offset(0, 0).Copy PasteCellAmount
```

**(3)** You never change the destination cells. After the first copy, you will have to move to the next row (else every copy command will overwrite the previous). For example

```
cell.Offset(0, -2).Copy PasteCell
cell.Offset(0, 0).Copy PasteCellAmount
Set PasteCell = PasteCell.Offset(1, 0)
Set PasteCellAmount = PasteCellAmount.Offset(1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Conditionally

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyConditionally()

    ' s - Source
    ' d - Destination
    ' l - Lookup
    ' v - Value
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = Sheet1 ' code name
    Dim slrg As Range: Set slrg = sws.Range("C2:C50")
    Dim svrg As Range: Set svrg = slrg.EntireRow.Columns("A") ' 'A2:A50'
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data") ' (tab) name
    Dim dlCell As Range: Set dlCell = dws.Range("C2")
    Dim dvCell As Range: Set dvCell = dlCell.EntireRow.Columns("A") ' 'A2'
    
    Dim slCell As Range, svCell As Range, sr As Long
    
    For Each slCell In slrg.Cells ' reference the current lookup cell
        sr = sr + 1 ' used to reference the current value cell
        If Len(CStr(slCell.Value)) > 0 Then ' is not blank
            Set svCell = svrg.Cells(sr) ' reference the value cell
            ' Write to the current destination cells.
            dlCell.Value = slCell.Value
            dvCell.Value = svCell.Value
            ' Reference the next destination cells (the ones below).
            Set dlCell = dlCell.Offset(1)
            Set dvCell = dvCell.Offset(1)
        'Else ' is blank; do nothing
        End If
    Next slCell

End Sub
```